# Javascript Replace using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to replace start from `@` to `º` with `0`
below is my string

I try its working only for 2 pair but not  working for 3 etc pair

**Example 01:**

**Input Data**

```
@8~Cº + @9~Cº
```

**Output**

```
0 + 0
```

**Example 02:**

**Input Data**

```
@11~Cº + @12~P1º - @13~Fº
```

**Output**

```
0+0+0
```

Below is my code

```
var tempRes = "@11~Cº + @12~P1º - @13~Fº";
tempRes = tempRes.replace(/@[0-9]~[A-Z]º/i,parseFloat(0));
```

Comment: In one output, you have spaces; in the other, you don't -- but there are spaces in both inputs. Do you want them or not?

Comment: @No spaces,both will without space

Comment: Okay. Please use the "edit" link to correct the question. Please also note the formatting fixes I applied for you: Taking the time to make sure your question is clearly formatted is important. There's an entire toolbar full of things to help you, and a lot of help available from the **[?]** button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
var s = '@11~Cº + @12~P1º + @13~Fº'
var r = s.replace(/@[^º]+º/g, 0);
//=> 0 + 0 + 0
```

---

**EDIT:** To remove spaces also

```
var r = s.replace(/\s*@[^º]+º\s*/g, 0);
//=> 0+0+0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regular expression to catch what you want

```
@.+?º
```

try this demo

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX7jE0/2)

to remove spaces use this regex

```
\s*@.+?º\s*
```

try this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX7jE0/3)

```
var input = '@11~Cº + @12~P1º + @13~Fº'
var output = input.replace(/\s*@.+?º\s*/g, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex in case you have multiple lines in your input:

```
[ ]*@[^º\n]*º[ ]*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU0aY4/2)

Explanation:

- `[ ]*` - Optional space(s)
- `@` - A `@` symbol
- `[^º\n]*` - 0 or more symbols other than `º` and a line break
- `[ ]*` - Optional space(s)